# how to check gprs connectivity on iphone 4

Tags: iphone

in my app i want to check the gprs connectivity on iphone if gprs  not present then i have to send sms so how can i do that please tell me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There's a sample application from Apple, showing how you can check the connectivity of an iOS device. The code is available here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html